# Как запустить приложение с помощью ярлыка, средствами Java?

Tags: java

Никак не получается запустить ярлык приложения (не `.exe`).

```
Runtime a = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

В данном случае не работает, пишет что:

> CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл

Comment: Нужно прочитать и распарсить файл `.lnk` (например, с помощью этого кода: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebling/WindowsShortcuts/master/org/stackoverflowusers/file/WindowsShortcut.java) и запустить уже тот файл, на который ссылается ярлык.

Comment: А что то проще возможно, можно конечно написать .bat который запускает этот ярлык, но зачем это костыль ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","notepad.exe.lnk");
Process process = pb.start();
```

После запуска используем

- process.getInputStream() - для ввода данных;
- process.getOutputStream() - для получения результатов;
- process.getErrorStream() - вывод ошибок.

Comment: Вы можете мне объяснить в чём может быть дело, запуск программы происходит через раз то есть ошибки не вы падает, но и программа не запускается ?

Comment: Сложный вопрос, когда не знаешь, что за программа. А в нашем случае мы еще получаем прослойку из cmd Process после старта можно получить один стрим на вход и два на выход (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) и уже там смотреть вывод ошибок. Для более точного контроля программы может стоит распарсить ярлык (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java) и запускать саму программу?